# Is it possible to "hide" a sub directory after rewriting root to that directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I'm trying to accomplish is basically hide the fact that the page is served from a subdirectory.

I currently have the following `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
RewriteRule (.*) /blog/$1
```

This does what I want. It serves pages from `/blog` while giving the user the impression of being in the root directory.

However if the user visits `http://www.example.com/blog` they get the same page. If possible I would actually like them to get `/blog/blog`.

The main reason this worries me is not because of real users but because of robots that might index the page with the wrong URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible but you have to cheat a little. Essentially THE_REQUEST never changes during rewriting so you can test for that.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog
RewriteRule . - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
RewriteRule (.*) /blog/$1
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond